# Riemannian metric

Tags: differential-geometry

This is a very simple question that I got confused. Is Riemannian metric a symmetric 2-**tensor** or symmetric 2-**tensor field**? Wikipedia says that it is a (0,2) [tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Riemannian_metrics) but my book says it is a tensor field. Are these things the same? What am I missing? (By the way, if it is a tensor field, I do not know what a symmetric tensor field is.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a symmetric 2 tensor field(*) on the manifold (let's say, $M$), and a symmetric 2 tensor when restricted to to the tangent space $T_pM$ for some $p \in M$. But people are often sloppy with this distinction.

Symmetry just means that (if the metric is denoted by $g$) 
$$g(p)(v,w) = g(p)(w,v) \quad \forall p \in M, v,w \in T_pM$$ 
which in local coordinates is equivalent to the statement that $$g_{ij} dx^i\otimes dx^j = g_{ji} dx^i\otimes dx^j $$

---

(*) more precisely: "(0,2) tensor field" or "covariant tensor field"

Comment: Is it covariat or contravariant?

Comment: covariant, sorry, this was wrong first.